# Json parameters are passed as null

Tags: json

I call the method like this:

Headers:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 116
Host: localhost:1234
```

POST method, URL:

```
http://localhost:1234/MyService.svc/json/MyMethod
```

Parameters:

```
{"email":"here@hotmail.com","json":{"array1":[],"array2":[],"array3":[]}}
```

Here is the method's signature:

```
public Result MyMethod(string email, Dictionary<string, object> json)
```

The method is called. email has ok value, but json has count zero. Why?

Comment: Help if you added your severside language to the tags! It would also help to show how you are generating the JOSN.

Comment: @HarHaHu Oh, I just add watch to json. It isn't null but it contains nothing.

Comment: @epascarello I'm not generating the json. That is the json. It could be {"email":"here@hotmail.com","json":{"some1":"some2"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was creating a new class which had these properties: List, List, List, and I changed the method:

```
public void MyMethod(string email, theNewClass json) ;
```

and it worked.