# Unsupported Media Type - REST Service

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I am trying to create a REST service which will take in **JSON** as input in a `POST` method. The service will then store this in a DB and return response. I created a class called **jsonFormat** as attempted in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667331/json-parameters-are-passed-as-null). The code for this class -

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Aj
 * This class forms the format of the JSON request which will be recieved from the App
 */
@XmlRootElement
public class JsonFormat {
    public double longitude;
    public double latitude;
    public long IMSI;

    public JsonFormat(){}

    public JsonFormat(double longitude,double latitude, long IMSI){
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.IMSI = IMSI;
    }

}
```

However, I am still getting the **unsupported media type HTTP 415** response.

I am testing by using the POSTMAN add on for chrome.

Here is my code for the service implementation -

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

/**
 * REST Web Service
 *
 * @author Aj
 */
@Path("Offers")
public class OffersResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of OffersResource
     */
    public OffersResource() {
    }

    @Path("/storeMovement")
    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String storeTrace(JsonFormat jsonObj) {
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
        String ret = "";
        try {
            RecordMovement re = new RecordMovement(jsonObj.longitude, jsonObj.latitude, jsonObj.IMSI);
            ret = re.Store();

            // Clear object
            re = null;
            System.gc();

            response.put("status", ret);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.put("status", "fail");
        }
        return response.toJSONString();
    }

    /**
     * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of OffersResource
     *
     * @param content representation for the resource
     * @return an HTTP response with content of the updated or created resource.
     */
    @PUT
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public void putJson(String content) {
    }
}
```

The JSON which I'm passing is -
`{"longitude": "77.681307",
                "latitude": "12.8250278",
                "IMSI": "404490585029957"}`

While submitting the request I made sure to set the type to `POST` and the URL is correct (`http://localhost:8080/Offers/webresources/Offers/storeMovement`).

Can somebody please take a look and advise what I'm doing wrong? I have gone through multiple sites where the error is mainly due to not setting the content type but this is clearly not the case here!

Comment: Just noticing, you are using @XmlRootElement for a class dealing with json. But you will probably need a parser like Jackson for your JsonFormat class.

Comment: @AndreasGnyp Do you mean I should use the ObjectMapper from Jackson in the constructor of my JSONFormat class?

Comment: Yes. I used it with methods, but it could work with a constructor, too. You also may have to write the mapper yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I changed from using a model to a string variable. I then use the `JSONParser` to parse the `json` String received as parameter followed by type casting it to a `JSONObject`. Here is my modified code -

```
@Path("/storeMovement")
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public String storeTrace(String json) {
    JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    String ret = "";

    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(json);
        JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;

        RecordMovement re = new RecordMovement((double) jsonObj.get("longitude"), (double) jsonObj.get("latitude"), (long) jsonObj.get("IMSI"));
        ret = re.Store();

        // Clear object
        re = null;
        System.gc();

        response.put("status", ret);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        response.put("status", "fail " + e.toString());
    }
    return response.toJSONString();
}
```